# UIView Animation using Frame only changes position and does not change size iOS

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, frame

So the below code moves the self.nowGamePiece to the center of the board, but it doesn't not change the size to 500 x 500. In fact, no matter what those values (width and height in CGRectMake) are, size doesn't change in this animation.

Why? self.nowGamePiece should also change its size to 500x 500 too!

```
//self.nowGamePiece is a UIView
    [UIView animateWithDuration:7 animations:^{
         self.nowGamePiece.frame = CGRectMake(self.gameBoardImageView.center.x,self.gameBoardImageView.center.y, 500, 500);
         //doing below only moves the self.nowGamePiece too. Size doesn't change
       //self.nowGamePiece.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 500, 500);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){
            return;
        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the autoResizingMask property of your view. I suspect your image is a subview of your nowGamePiece view, and it's just not resizing the image when the frame of the superview gets changed.

```
self.nowGamePiece.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
self.nowGamePiece.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```

Comment: image is not a subview of self.gamePiece. Image is just an image in the same uiview as the self.gamePiece is in. With your solution, I am still getting the same results. Still only position changes, and size does not.

Comment: Just forget about self.gameBoardImageView. If I do self.nowGamePiece.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 500, 500); the self.nowGamePiece moves to 100,100, but the size doesn't change.

Comment: You mean the frame doesn't actually get bigger? I thought you meant it visibly doesn't scale.

There's no reason to have an empty completion block, you should just change that to `nil`. I don't think that's related but.. just a side comment.

Comment: Also, just to verify it should work, I used your code, in isolation from any other code, and simply used a background color to see the view change. It does in fact change frame..

Your problem has to be something else, which is why I have been asking you questions about how things are set up.

I notice you answered your own question below - I can't comment, so I'll ask you here:
Were you already using a transform before applying this animation?

Comment: are you sure in your code the size also change as well as the position? They both change? I wasn't using any transformation before applying animation with frame.

Comment: Yes, they both change. Here's a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKzIjjH92mE

There's gotta be something going on aside from the code you posted here.

Comment: haha wow thanks so much for the video. So it seems like I am doing something wrong else in my code. I found an alternative solution, but I want to give you some credit if you answer this question

Answer (score 0):

I think this method may be bugged. I solved it using transform instead.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:7 animations:^{
    self.nowGamePiece.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeScale(7.0, 7.0);
    self.nowGamePiece.center = CGPointMake(self.gameBoardImageView.center.x, self.gameBoardImageView.center.y);
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    return;
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
//self.nowGamePiece is a UIView
[UIView animateWithDuration:7 animations:^{

CGRect frame = self.nowGamePiece.frame;
frame = CGRectMake(self.gameBoardImageView.center.x, self.gameBoardImageView.center.y, 500, 500);
self.nowGamePiece.frame = frame;   

} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    return;
}];
```

Comment: still the same result. It only moves the self.nowGamePiece to the center of the board, and the size doesn't change. I mean your code is basically same as mine. There is no difference.

Comment: are you using auto layout?